# MongoDB how to pull id objects from inside a model array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a model called "Popular", where I have an array called "PopularPosts" where I store Post ids from a model "Post". I can store these ids inside this array without problems

Popular model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const PopularSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        PopularPosts: [{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Post',
            required: false,
        }],
        createdAt: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now,
        }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
  );
  
module.exports = mongoose.model("Popular", PopularSchema);
```

Posts

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        img: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        category: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Category",
        },
        desc: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now,
        }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
  );
  
module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema);
```

But when I do a get request, I return from the array only the ids instead of all the post information. so I tried to create a Populate to pull the post information of each id when making a request

```
const Popular = require('../../models/Popular');

class FindPopularPosts {
    async find(req, res) {
        const { id } = req.params;

        try {
            const popularPosts = await Popular.findById({id}).populate({
                path: 'PopularPosts',
                model: 'Post', 
            }).lean();

            return res.status(200).json(popularPosts);
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(500).json(err);
        }
    }
} 

module.exports = new FindPopularPosts();
```

Postman eror:

```
{
    "stringValue": "\"{ id: '63b5a895fbb93698183d75d2' }\"",
    "valueType": "Object",
    "kind": "ObjectId",
    "value": {
        "id": "63b5a895fbb93698183d75d2"
    },
    "path": "_id",
    "reason": {},
    "name": "CastError",
    "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"{ id: '63b5a895fbb93698183d75d2' }\" (type Object) at path \"_id\" for model \"Popular\""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what did you get if you try to query your popular post like this ? :

```
 const { id } = req.params;
 try {
        const popularPosts = await Popular.findById(id).exec();

            return res.status(200).json(popularPosts);
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(500).json(err);
        }
```

Update2 : try again like this

```
    const { id } = req.params;
 try {
      const popularPosts = await Popular.findById(id)
        .populate('Post').exec();

      return res.status(200).json(popularPosts);
     } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json(err);
     }
```

Comment: {
    "_id": "63b5a895fbb93698183d75d2",
    "PopularPosts": [
        "63ade1d84cbbd498656dbb9d",
        "63ac9cbccec4d9f35c4f4d1f",
        "63ade6314cbbd498656dbbc1"
    ],
    "createdAt": "2023-01-04T16:25:57.775Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-01-04T16:25:57.775Z",
    "__v": 0
}

Comment: I would like it to return me post information instead of the id

Comment: Oh my bad i completly not see your second schema attach to your first schema that why you want to populate... , so i reupdate my answer and check if this can work.